Linux boot with raid1 for ESP and /boot/grub with OS on btrfs raid1
So for a bit of context: I am installing artix linux on my custom build NAS/Media Server. I am asking here because my question seems to be more about grub than artix itself. The main idea is that as soon as the system is up an running I should be able to do any kind of maintenance or troubleshooting with ssh as long as there is at least one of my system ssds working. If the OS is on raid1 then in my opinion the bootloader should have equivalent redundancy(what good is redundant OS if it can't boot). So for a setup with two ssds for the OS let's call these ssds sda and sdb. The partition layout would then look something like this:

sda1, sdb1(md raid1) /boot/efi: EFI System Partitions where the .EFI file resides and potentially nvram cache
sda2, sdb2(md raid1) /boot/grub: Where grub configs reside
sda3, sdb3(btrfs raid1) /root: root filesystem including /boot where kernel and initramfs image[s] reside

Obviously there are additional drives for data but they are not important here.
My questions are:

UEFI will not be able to detect the md raid on the ESP. In case UEFI writes its nvram cache here the OS should sync the md raid1 after boot. Per this blog post it is possible. Will it work?
Is it possible to have /boot/grub on a different partition from /boot itself?
Can I have /boot/grub in btrfs raid1 as well? If I understand correctly, grub can't write to btrfs so grubenv would be readonly, which, I guess, would conflict with grub-reboot
If so what happens to files like grubenv when /boot/grub is again on md raid1? Can grub be configured so that it "knows" it is installed on md raid so it will write to both disks at once or will there be a need for sync work after boot here as well? I am concerned about this because I want to be able to use for example grub-reboot to maybe boot to another snapshot of the system.
Can I have kernel and initramfs images on a different partition than grub files are located? In this case they will be on btrfs raid1.

With such a setup I hope to be able to ssh into the initramfs system if btrfs can't mount because one drive is missing. Is there something flawed with this setup? How do I configure grub so that it works?
